# BeautifulSoup 'markup' is not defined

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Following this documentation, I have done everything correctly: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Yet, I am getting the error of 'markup' not defined when running my code. The URL is just for an example of the error.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

URL = 'https://www.theverge.com/rss/index.xml'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")


output = soup

print(output)
```

**Error:**

```
import requests...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\Dev\python\rss_scrape.py in 
      7 page = requests.get(URL)
      8 
----> 9 soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
      10 
     11 

NameError: name 'markup' is not defined
```

I'm not sure what the issue is here? I have lxml installed as well, so I'm totally lost. Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Well, where in your code have you defined the variable `markup`? is this your full code?

Comment: Yeah man, I'm an idiot, I realized once Hitesh answered that I didn't change it to 'page'. Dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# try this once
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://www.theverge.com/rss/index.xml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
print(soup)
```

Comment: I got the same error, but it said 'response' is not defined. Makes no sense to me based on the documentation.

Comment: This worked. I see what I was doing wrong! You rock